# sed "$" not acting as end of line character

Tags: bash, sed

Using Ubuntu 18, with the bash shell

The "$" character is not behaving as it should for end of line match in sed.

When I try:

`sed '/^>/ s/$/_new/g' <file>`

this should result in

`>sometext_new`

but I am getting

`_newetext`

This may be related to this question: 
[Error while matching End of line with $ in Sed command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859790/error-while-matching-end-of-line-with-in-sed-command)
but that was using csh and had variable assignments which I do not have.

I have tried turning off shell expansion `set -f ;` but this did not help

I have tried `sed '/^>/ s/"$"/_new/g' <file>`

this turned $ into a literal character, resulting in no substitution

I would appreciate any help in restoring the previous behaviour of $ as end of line character in sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<file>` almost certainly has Windows-style (CRLF) line endings:

```
$ printf '>sometext\n' | sed '/^>/ s/$/_new/'
>sometext_new
```

but

```
$ printf '>sometext\r\n' | sed '/^>/ s/$/_new/'
_newetext
```

---

If you want to preserve the CRLF line endings, but replace text at the (Windows) EOL, you could use `s/\r$/_new\r/`

ex. (piping to `cat -A` to make the line endings explicit)

```
$ printf '>sometext\r\n' | sed '/^>/ s/\r$/_new\r/' | cat -A
>sometext_new^M$
```

OTOH if you want to convert the whole file to Unix endings, you could use

```
sed -e 's/\r$//' -e '/^>/ s/$/_new/'
```

or convert the file with `dos2unix` before using `sed`.

*Note that the `g` modifier has no effect when a replacement is anchored to the end (or start) of a pattern.*

Comment: file <file>
returned ```ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators```
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ColinAnthony yes that would do it - I've added some suggestions depending on whether you want to preserve the CRLF formating or not